Request retagging [axum] for Rust web library
The axum tag was created for the Axum programming language, an actor-centric language by Microsoft focused on concurrency. It was only a short lived experiment, however, and it ceased all effort after a few years.
Totally distinct is the axum web server library for Rust that has become one of the more popular frameworks. It currently resides in the rust-axum tag.
As a curator for the rust tag, I constantly see users mistagging their axum web server questions with axum. I periodically go through and fix them, as do others, but due to the lack of any activity in the axum language (only three proper questions with the last one from 2011) I feel this dynamic can be flipped. The current state of the tag indicates the issue.
I humbly request that the language be retagged to axum-lang (or similar) so that the web server library can assume the axum tag (with rust-axum as synonym).

"I humbly request that the language be retagged to axum-lang (or similar) so that the web server library can assume the axum tag (with rust-axum as synonym)." - this is going to cause the exact same problem as right now, but in reverse (or with some new future thing that uses the same name). [tag:axum] should be either a synonym of one of the two tags, or removed fully, and leave [axum-lang] and [rust-axum] to avoid ambiguity

@Zoe If [axum] as a synonym to [rust-axum] is better down the line than the inverse, then that's acceptable to me. But the point is that "axum" should by default refer to the rust library. I don't expect any practical ambiguity since no one has asked about the language in 13 years. If one does come a long, any mistagging can be easily seen and fixed. And of course if there comes a new "axum" in town (or a new resurgence in the language), this topic can be revisited.

Yeah, it's just easier to deal with a potential synonym target change than a full tag disambiguation. Avoiding ambiguity as much as possible when revisiting tag names (or even when creating tags, but too late for that here)  saves a lot of future work. That aside, changing synonym targets is a few clicks and a couple minutes of waiting for the system to process, while cleaning up an entire tag can take anywhere from minutes for a single person to weeks for many people. in either case, [axum] is now a synonym of [rust-axum], and the three axum-lang questions have been moved to their own tag

@Zoe gotcha, appreciated!

I would have gone for axum-microsoft even to really hammer down its the typical Microsoft brainfart. Methinks somewhere in the future a new programming language will sprout with that name, given we are getting two new programming languages per day now.
